# how does laravel handle locking and concurrent updates?

Tags: database, laravel, locking

Grails, by default, uses optimistic locking.  It maintains an update count, and it checks this and throws an exception (and rolls the second one back) if two people try to update the same record at the same time.

What is laravel's strategy for concurrent updates?

If the answer is nothing (i.e. overwrite), This would result in a broken application. E.g. if you have an api which happens to update a user's "last logged in" value, and you have a backend admin application which allows an administrator to say "ban" a user, then we could have the situation where the ban update is overwriten (and lost) by the api update.  In this case we need to use pessimistic locking, which is not understood by many developers and can easily result in deadlocking or slowdowns.  Or separate the tables into a lot of small tables, but this also has its issues.

Comment: (Laravel aside, many applications / SQL update usages are intrinsically broken..)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#pessimistic-locking

Comment: Sharelocks look interesting, but would need to know in detail how it works and what it acually does at the DB level to know if it will work in a mulit-server multi-user system, and how it fails and how to catch such fails.